# Angular-Material || md-menu not closing on mobile on click of an item

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-material

I am using Angular-Material in one of my phonegap projects, I have a menu (md-menu). This menu is working fine on browser on wider layouts, but the menu doesn't close itself on click of a md-button when app is deployed on Android or iPhone or even on browser when the browser size is reduced to the size of a phone. The Menu closes when clicked outside of the menu, but It should also close when a button is clicked. Can someone point out anything missing in code below.

Here is my code :

```
<md-menu>
<button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v  fa-lg"></i>
</button>
<md-menu-content>
    <md-menu-item>
        <md-button ng-click="goToHome();"><span><i
                class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i> Search</span>
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
    <md-menu-item>
        <md-button ng-click="goToCreate();"><span><i
                class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i>  Create</span>
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
</md-menu-content></md-menu>
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and got a temporary solution for this issues. this link will be help full for you http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNwyrB

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be inject `$mdMenu` in your controller and call `$mdMenu.hide()` in your ngClick callback.

example:

```
angular.module('demo').controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $mdMenu) {
  $scope.goToHome = function() {
    $mdMenu.hide();
    // doSomeThing....
  }
});
```